# Android Edittext number only

Tags: android, android-input-method

I have a a Edittext field that is dynamically created I have it so that the input method is number only.  However it is still possible to paste text into the field.  Is there anyway of preventing this without having to do post validation?

My code to for input method is currently:

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this method

```
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Comment: Yea that was where I had started before I changed it to the above, that code doesn't work either. I may have to go down the option of stopping blocking pasting on number fields, but I would rather not.

Comment: Worked like a charm, many thanks, if you have the time could you add an explanation as to why that code works?  if not no problem it does the job :-)

Comment: Glad to help. You could have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) to learn about `InputType`. If this answer was helpful to you, please consider ticking it as accepted. Happy coding! @user2029541

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done is almost correct for copy-paste condition you can use this

```
    Field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0)

   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setInputType` rather than `setRawInputType` like this:

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```